# How to do if statement in MVC EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hey im sure this is a simple question but im completely new to MVC EF . I have a view that takes 3 inputs . 2 are Dates and the other one is the ID of the roller-coaster ride which is called "ID". If all the inputs are filled it gives you the number of guest that Rode that specific Ride . If the ID is NULL then it gives out the most popular Ride and the number of guest that rode that specific ride. My issue is how to get the right sentence to appear. Right now the sentence says "The number of guests in the given date range was" but the problem is that it says the same thing when it is null . So it says "The number of guests in the given date range 5 7" . Where 5 is the most popular Ride and 7 is the number of guest. i rather have the sentence say "the most popular ride was 5 and it had 7 guest" . So basically what im asking is if there is some type of If-else statement i can use in the view to get the right sentence to appear? Below is my code for the view and controller

```
@model IEnumerable<ThemeParkManagementSystem.Models.RideCount>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Reports</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Reports", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <text> Date 1 </text>
        @Html.TextBox("date1")
        <text> Date 2 </text>
        @Html.TextBox("date2")
        <text> Ride ID </text>
        @Html.TextBox("id")<input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>
            <text>The number of guests in the given date range for </text> @ViewData["RideID"] @ViewData["GuestCount"]
        </th>
    </tr>
</table> 

private tpdatabaseEntities db = new tpdatabaseEntities();
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date1, DateTime? date2, int? id)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        Nullable<int> popularRideID = db.topRides(date1, date2).ToList<Nullable<int>>().FirstOrDefault();

        var popularID = popularRideID;

        DateTime? d1 = date1;
        DateTime? d2 = date2;
        Nullable<int> numOfGuest = db.Guestcount(d1, d2, popularID).ToList<Nullable<int>>().FirstOrDefault();
        var guestCount = numOfGuest.Value;

        ViewData["RideID"] = popularID;
        ViewData["GuestCount"] = numOfGuest;


        return View();

    }
    else
    {
        Nullable<int> countList = db.RideCount(date1, date2, id).ToList<Nullable<int>>().FirstOrDefault();
        var rideCount = countList.Value;
        ViewData["RideCount"] = rideCount;
    }
    return View();
}
```

[image: output when the ID is NULL]

Comment: Why don't you prepare the message in the Controller and pass it trough the ViewData or ViewBag? You can have all the if logic you like

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Steve in the comments because it is probably wiser to leave that logic in the controller. However, as you are new to MVC EF maybe this solution can help you in another scenario. As you are just returning a single value from your search, there is no need to use an IEnumerable model.

If you use a model of type ThemeParkManagementSystem.Models.RideCount this will give you access to it's values in the view and then you can use a simple if statement as shown in the code below.

Not the most optimal solution, but could come in handy in future scenarios.

```
    @model ThemeParkManagementSystem.Models.RideCount

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

        <h2>Reports</h2>

        <p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Reports", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <text> Date 1 </text>
                @Html.TextBox("date1")
                <text> Date 2 </text>
                @Html.TextBox("date2")
                <text> Ride ID </text>
                @Html.TextBox("id")<input type="submit" value="Search" />
            }
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>

                <th>
        @if (model.id==null){
                    <text>The number of guests in the given date range for </text> @ViewData["RideID"] @ViewData["GuestCount"]
        }
        else{
            Other text value
        }

                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Yes ...that also worked...i fixed that issue but now im trying to do something else ...mind if i ask ?

Comment: Yeah sure. Ask aaway

Comment: Okay so i have the functionality of picking specific rides as well as the ability of finding the most popular ride . What i want to do now is when the user types "ALL" for rideID  i want it to display the number of guest for every Ride .I already created the store procedure in the DBMS and i imported it in my project as a ComplexType but now im having issues figuring out how to display that table or even return it correctly in my controller if(id == 888 )
            {
                var wholeTable = db.allRides(date1, date2);
                ViewData["Result"] = wholeTable;
            }

Comment: You should ask a new question for this as it's unrelated and you'll find better help that way. You can also then post all your related code again  so that it's easier to help you.